# Replacing one test string with another in particular column and preserving delimiters

Tags: linux, awk

I have a space delimited text file:

```
NC_005943.1 RefSeq CDS 3259 4213 . + 0 gene_id "ND1";
NC_005943.1 RefSeq CDS 4421 5462 . + 0 gene_id "ND2";
NC_005943.1 RefSeq CDS 5850 7418 . + 0 gene_id "COX1";
NC_005943.1 RefSeq CDS 7532 8215 . + 0 gene_id "COX2";
NC_005943.1 RefSeq CDS 8357 8563 . + 0 gene_id "ATP8";
```

I need to replace the string "gene ID" in $9 with "transcript_id".

Doing:

```
awk -F " " '{ if ($9 == "gene_id") $9="transcript_id";}2' OFS=, genes_2.gtf | head
```

Gives me:

```
NC_005943.1,RefSeq,CDS,3259,4213,.,+,0,transcript_id,"ND1";
NC_005943.1,RefSeq,CDS,4421,5462,.,+,0,transcript_id,"ND2";
NC_005943.1,RefSeq,CDS,5850,7418,.,+,0,transcript_id,"COX1";
NC_005943.1,RefSeq,CDS,7532,8215,.,+,0,transcript_id,"COX2";
NC_005943.1,RefSeq,CDS,8357,8563,.,+,0,transcript_id,"ATP8";
```

...comma separated delimiter.

I need to preserve the space delimiter.  I know it's something in awk -F but have had trouble changing the flag to a space.

thanks so much.

Comment: try changing `OFS=,` to `OFS=" "`

Comment: @iruvar Or removing `OFS=,` since `OFS=" "` is the default.

Comment: `-F " "` is setting FS to the default value `" "` it'd have anyway so that statement is useless and then `OFS=,` is setting OFS to a value you don't want it to have (`,`) instead of the default value that you actually DO want it to have, `" "`. So, just don't do that, remove both `-F " "` and `OFS=,`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
awk '{ $9 = "transcript_id"; print }' genes_2.gtf
```

Comment: Or `awk '$9 == "gene_id" { $9 = "transcript_id" }; 1' file.gtf` if the modification needs to happen only when the 9th field is exactly `gene_id`.